# Why does 'padding' sometimes count inside an element width, and sometimes not?

Tags: css, input, width, padding

I've made a bookmarklet that, among other things, loads a form in a "popup" div. I reset every CSS tag known to mankind on every element I create, and as far as I can tell examining it in firebug, no CSS tag is "bleeding through". However, on some pages, the input width includes its padding:

```
input.clientWidth = input.style.width
```

on other pages, the input width does *not* include the padding:

```
input.clientWidth = input.style.width + input.style.paddingLeft + input.style.paddingRight
```

As such, here is a small code snippet:

```
input.style.width = '300px';
input.style.border = '1px solid grey';
input.style.padding = '20px';
alert(input.clientWidth);
```

On some pages, this alerts 298 (300 - the 1px border), and on other pages this alerts 338 (300 - the 1px border + 20 + 20). What causes this? And more importantly, what can I do to get consistent behavior?

**Edit:**

This is all in the same browser - Firefox 3.6.8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For IE it could be that some pages are in quirks mode where the box model is not the standard one used.

The `document.compatMode` would be `CSS1Compat` for standards mode and `BackCompat` for quirks mode. You can branch out the calculation based on that.

Obviously it would help if you showed us two separate pages that vary, but since it's a bookmarklet and it's invoked on different sites it would make sense.

Comment: Thank you! This was the problem (although it had nothing to do with IE). Assuming I want consistency across all these pages, what are the various compatibility modes I need to check for?

Comment: Those are the only 2 modes AFAIK.

Comment: thank you very much. I am somewhat surprised to note that amazon.com uses BackCompat!

Answer (score 0):

For consistent behavior, you can factor the padding, margin and border into every width, i.e. (pseudocode)

`totalWidth = input.width + input.padding + input.margin + input.border;`

Obviously, you have to do some string manipulation to pick out the integers there and then add them.